# Add column and row to multidimensional torch.tensor (kind of wrap-up or padding)

Tags: pytorch

The tensor should be updated with additional row-zeros (bottom) and column-zeros (on the right side).

My solution will be provided below. Is there any better (actually simpler) one?

**input:** («ones» are just for clarification - figures might be different, because in my case there is a tensor exactly the same size but with real values in it)

```
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.]],

         [[1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.]],

         [[1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [1., 1., 1.]]]])
```

**output:**

```
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

         [[1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0.]],

         [[1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [1., 1., 1., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0.]]]])
```

**possible solution:**

```
x1 = torch.ones(1, 3, 3, 3)

z2 = torch.cat((torch.cat((x1[0, 0, :], torch.zeros(1, 3)), 0), torch.zeros(4, 1)), 1)
z3 = torch.cat((torch.cat((x1[0, 1, :], torch.zeros(1, 3)), 0), torch.zeros(4, 1)), 1)
z4 = torch.cat((torch.cat((x1[0, 2, :], torch.zeros(1, 3)), 0), torch.zeros(4, 1)), 1)

output_t = torch.zeros(1, 3, 4, 4)

output_t[0, 0, :] = z2
output_t[0, 1, :] = z3
output_t[0, 2, :] = z4

output_t
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with pytorch's `torch.nn.ConstantPad?d` functions.

```
from torch import nn

x1 = torch.ones(1, 3, 3, 3)

pad_value = 0
pad_func = nn.ConstantPad1d((0, 1, 0, 1), pad_value)

output_t = pad_func(x1)
```

You could also exchange `nn.ConstantPad1d` with `nn.ConstantPad2d` or `nn.ConstantPad3d`. All did what you want with the same settings.

Then there is also numpy's `np.pad`.

```
x1 = torch.ones(1, 3, 3, 3)

pad_value = 0

output_n = np.pad(x1.numpy(), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 1)), "constant", constant_values=pad_value)
output_t = torch.from_numpy(output_n)
```

Comment: Works great! Tiny correction in notation `torch.nn.ConstantPad1d`.

Comment: Glad it works. `nn.ConstantPad1d` was intensional as it is common to import `nn` on its own. I'll make the import explicit instead.